# Dot subgraph edge position and direction

Tags: graphviz, dot

I want the edges to point from one subgraph to another, and not from one node to a subgraph.

Furthermore can I control the lenght of the edges?

```
digraph G {
compound=true;

node[shape=box];

subgraph cluster0 {
  color=blue;
  label="Top";
  a;
}

subgraph cluster1 {
  color=magenta;
  label="Middle";
  b;
}

subgraph cluster2 {
  color=green;
  label="Bottom";
  c;
}

a -> b[dir=back,ltail=cluster2,lhead=cluster1]
b -> c[dir=back,ltail=cluster1,lhead=cluster0]

}
```

[image]

Comment: `edge[ minlen = 2 ];` on line 5 controls the length of the edges.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to make sure that your `ltail` and `lhead` are correctly positioned:

```
digraph G 
{
    compound=true;
    node[ shape=box ];
    edge[ minlen = 2 ];

    subgraph cluster0 
    {
        color = blue;
        label = "Top";
        a;
    }

    subgraph cluster1 
    {
        color = magenta;
        label = "Middle";
        b;
    }

    subgraph cluster2 
    {
        color = green;
        label = "Bottom";
        c;
    }

    // here:
    a -> b[ dir = back, lhead = cluster1, ltail = cluster0 ]
    b -> c[ dir = back, lhead = cluster2, ltail = cluster1 ]

}
```

yields

[image]